# Data from Partial view is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view:

```
@model BasicFinanceUI.Models.TransactionLine

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cmbCategory0" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Category:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId,
                                   new SelectList(Model.References.Categories, "Value", "Text", Model.CategoryId), "Select one",
                                   new { @onchange = "populateSubCategory(0)", @class = "cmbCategory form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This partial view is loaded from a List<> of objects on my main view:

```
@foreach (var line in Model.Transaction.TransactionLines)
{
    @Html.Partial("_TransactionLine", line)
}
```

The partial view(s) are loaded fine, with the correct data.

But when I want to save the data - it seems my list has a row, but no data in the row. I'm new to Partial views, but it seems MVC doesn't map the partial view data to the List<> which created the list of partial views.

Am I doing something wrong?

In the controller, when I am trying to read the data into my objects to send them back to the database, I am doing this:

```
item.TransactionLines = new List<TransactionLineDto>();
foreach (var line in model.Transaction.TransactionLines)
{
    item.TransactionLines.Add(new TransactionLineDto
        {
            Id = line.Id,
            CostCentreId = line.CostCentreId,
            SubCategoryId = line.SubCategoryId,
            TransactionId = model.Transaction.Id,
            Amount = line.Amount
        });
}
```

But, what I am finding is that all values are 0. It seems the partial view doesn't return the data back to the View's model. Is that expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried 'Partial' and 'RenderPartial'. Not sure why is right though, as they both result in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the HTML you will see that the name attributes of the dropdowns inside the partial will be `CategoryId`. This is wrong because it should be something like `Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CategoryId`. Otherwise ASP.NET MVC will not be able to properly map the values to the model. Easiest solution to fix this would be to use a for loop and move partial view HTML inside the main view.

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.Transaction.TransactionLines.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cmbCategory0" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Category:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[i].CategoryId,
                                   new SelectList(x.Transaction.TransactionLines[i].References.Categories, "Value", "Text", x.Transaction.TransactionLines[i].CategoryId), "Select one",
                                   new { @onchange = "populateSubCategory(0)", @class = "cmbCategory form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done this now.... Any idea if I can also change the names in the 'label for=""? Need to append the counter number to the name, so, "cmbCategory1 ...2,... 3... etc

Comment: @Craig Can you try this? `<label for="cmbCategory@i" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Category:</label>`